# Programatically Assigning AutomationIds to Templated Controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-ui-automation

I've got a control template that looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    <Setter>
</Style>
```

I've been able to create a setter tag to assign an automationid to the instantiated objects. But as one would expect all of the controls have the same ID.

There's some further XAML that defines 3 thumbs (center, left, and right), I'm wanting to define their IDs in such a way that they would like:

Center_1
Right_1
Left_1

Center_2
Right_2
Left_2

Any ideas on how I can make this happen?

I'm guessing I would need to have a static member variable to track the number of instantiated objects (and then use that to increment the name value), but beyond that I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [Uid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613571(v=vs.110).aspx) property should be the property you need to set.